# Will reversing the polarity of a K thermocouple damage it?

Tags: thermocouple

I have a K thermocouple connected to a [MAX31855KASA+T](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Maxim-Integrated/MAX31855KASA%2BT?qs=ffX8NcjNb2TujkrPyW1z%252Bg%3D%3D) IC supplied by 3.3V.  I mistakenly reversed the polarity and was taking reading from it for about 1hr.  I am noticing the instrument is now somewhat inaccurate.  Freezing water was registering 10F and boiling water about 180F.  Did the polarity reversal damage the instrument?  I have replaced the IC but am still noticing the inaccuracy..  Isn't this just measuring the dV across two dissimilar metals, I imagine this would be pretty robust.

Comment: Are you compensating the values appropriately in code?  See this how-to and code at adafruit.com.  https://learn.adafruit.com/calibrating-sensors/maxim-31855-linearization

Comment: **CLOSE VOTERS** The question has two good answers by two high rep users and is entirely understandable. I suggest that you EITHER remove your votes, and/or explain why you have downvoted and/or edit the question to improve it and/or make suggestions to the OP re what improvements are needed. If none of this is done the question is **VERY** likely to be reopened if closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the thermocouple cannot be damaged by reversing it.

More likely you have an error in your cold junction compensation or extension lead wire polarity.

All thermocouple wire in the sensor circuit must have the correct polarity- if there is a piece that is reversed you’ll get an error approximately double the temperature difference between the ends of the incorrect piece. Similarly, any temperature difference between the IC chip and the junctions between K wire and copper will show up as approximately 1:1 error.

Answer (score 3):

It won't be damaged.

A thermocouple is passive -- it *generates* a small voltage (millivolts) based on the temperature difference between its ends. The readout IC amplifies and compensates this voltage (which can be positive or negative depending on temperature) to provide a usable output.

Reversing it will generally mean that the temperature reading will be inverted (from 25 C) -- so a reversed thermocouple at 29 C will read 21 C etc.

Freezing water needs to be pure water (use deionized water for the water rand the ice) to get reasonably close to 0 C (32 F). Boiling water will be at a lower temperature at higher altitudes -- every 1000 m of altitude will decrease the boiling point by about 3 C.